# video playing sample on iPhone using libffmpeg

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ffmpeg, avfoundation

can someone please provide a reference or an example on usage of libffmpeg library for playing video files not supported by apple.

Let consider mkv file.
I suppose the library decodes and passes the raw media data to AVFoundation objects to play it on device. Am I right ?

Comment: Hey, I've spent almost the half of the day researching and experimenting on this but still failing. Yes I've     
Put some effort into researching the problem,
    Attempted to write some code yourself
    Attempted to debug your code when it has failed, and
    Some basic, fundamental knowledge of your tools?.
If your able to support to make the question better than I'll be happy do make it better. But please dont spam

Comment: Sorry if it came off as rude, but nowhere in your question do you indicate what your prior efforts were. It would also be good to show code that isn't working and what errors you are receiving. That stuff helps us figure out where you are going wrong. The way your question is written right now it sounds like you haven't tried anything.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful example is ffmpeg4iphone project it does have `Player` class which does actually playing the video and audio channel

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to look at is [kxmovie](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie) project on GitHub.